# How to know what is slowing down my drupal site

Tags: 7, performance

My site is still in early stages of development and the page load is getting slower day by day. Even though i really think twice before installing a module for something and try to get it done with jQuery.

Is there a way to know "What Exactly (A module or my theme templates) is slowing down the site ?".

thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can install devel module and enable show queries so you can look at what queries run your website.Find out havy query and try to optimize.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I see that queries by "DrupalDatabaseCache::set --> INSERT INTO cache_form" are taking longer time. Is DrupalDatabaseCache a must ? cant i turn it off?

Comment: Perhaps your cache_form table is getting very large? Try truncating it and see whether that helps. If it keeps growing too fast, you may also want to put an index on crucial columns to speed things up.

Comment: Disabling form_cache is not a good idea. I don't think that you can :))). May be you can write some crone to flush form_cache ? if it's your issue ?

Comment: Yap truncating the table helped. Just interested in knowing what "form_cache" is made for .

Comment: form_cache used for validating forms each form request stores it's cache. So after submitting drupal retrieves the cache and checks submitted values with cache.